# Google Maps Permission automatically

Tags: android, google-maps

I've released my App some Days ago. Now the Problem is that the users have to activate the Google Maps permission on the App Manager. What do i have to do that it is activatet automatically?
I've got these permissions in the Android Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `Android Version >= M`, the permission has to be asked at `Runtime`, which can not be done automatically. A general `Runtime Permission` asking code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                    (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }, 1); // 1 is requestCode
        return;

    }
}
```

Handle Request:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {

    case 1:
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(your_activity.this,"PERMISSION_DENIED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          else {
                Toast.makeText(your_activity.this,"PERMISSION_GRANTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // permission granted do something
          }
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i forgot to check for the permission in the Map class!

Answer (score 0):

you can set `targetSdkVersion` inside your gradle file to 22 or lower that enables all your permission by default at install time, but better solution is handling `Runtime Permission` in your code with `targetSdkVersion` 23 or higher

Comment: But this does not work in Markus' case since he already published his app. Google added some friggin lame check in Google Play which prevents you to downgrade the app release to a version with the old permission concept. You cannot even re-publish the old version if you ever published a version > 22(!).